# Drupal: Custom Content Type validation

Tags: validation, drupal, cck

I've created a custom content type with CCK.

If I need to add some custom code for validating fields of this content type's record form, where do I add the code and which functions are best for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) and the [#validation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate) attribute on the form. You would of cause have to implement this in your own module.

Answer (score 3):

The form api is what you use to validate, you'll be crafting your own validation function.  I'm going to assume you are using D6

There's a less painful way:
http://drupal.org/project/validation_api

This module lets you make php code or regex for any given field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To create your own module to implement form validation I suggest this method:
[create a new module for content type field validation in drupal](http://www.webscaped.com/articles/2009/03/custom-field-validation-in-drupal/)

Comment: You could expand your answer a little to summarize what the linked article says.